# Replacing / by \ in a string with ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I need to replace all the / by \ in a string stored in a variable.

I'm just trying to do it a simple as possible to test it with a debug, but no matter how I try it I dont get the expected result of just replacing character to character. I think it's probably just a single/double quote problem or maybe the \ needs to be escaped in a certain way I don't know.

```
vars:
    - SecGroup: '/stuff/foo/thing'
tasks:
    - name: Display modified var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ SecGroup | replace('/','\') }}"
```

Expected output : \stuff\foo\thing

Output with differents tries :

```
- name: Display modified var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ SecGroup | replace('/','\') }}"

TASK [Display modified var] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "stufffoothing"
}


- name: Display modified var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ SecGroup | replace('/','\\') }}"

TASK [Display modified var] 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution."}


- name: Display modified var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ SecGroup | replace('/','\\\') }}"

TASK [Display modified var] 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution."}


- name: Display modified var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ SecGroup | replace('/','\\\\') }}"

TASK [Display modified var] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "\\\\stuff\\\\foo\\\\thing"
}
```

I also tried to revert the quotes :

```
- name: Display modified var
      debug:
        msg: '{{ SecGroup | replace("/","\") }}'

TASK [Display modified var]
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution."}
```

I can't explain the output of this one

```
- name: Display modified var
      debug:
        msg: '{{ SecGroup | replace("/","\\") }}'

TASK [Display modified var] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "\\\\stuff\\\\foo\\\\thing"
}
```

Comment: I am really surprised that ansible doesn't throw an error when you use ` "{{ SecGroup | replace('/','\') }}"`. Within double quoted scalars, the backslash can be used to escape (this set)[.2/spec.html#id2776092] of escaped characters. Had you looked over that list, you'd see that the single quote cannot be escaped, which makes your scalar invalid, and that the backslash has to be escaped. But maybe ansible uses templates to generate YAML loads, instead of loading YAML and expanding the scalars after loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've stumbled upon an edge case that involves the interaction between YAML escaping and Python escaping.  The only way I was able to get it to work was introducing a guard character -- something to ensure that the `\` isn't the last character in the expression, which we then remove with a subsequent `replace()` filter.  Here I'm using a semicolon (`;`), but you could use anything that you're certain won't be in your `SecGroup` string.  Note that your choice of quotes is significant; quoting the entire string with single quotes inhibits YAML escaping:

```
- name: With guard character
  debug:
    msg: '{{ SecGroup | replace("/","\;") | replace(";", "") }}'
```

Outputs:

```
TASK [With guard character] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "\\stuff\\foo\\thing"
}
```

Which is exactly what you want (remembering that a single `\` is encoded as `\\` in JSON output).

---

Regarding this:

```
- name: Display modified var
      debug:
        msg: '{{ SecGroup | replace("/","\\") }}'

TASK [Display modified var] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "\\\\stuff\\\\foo\\\\thing"
}
```

You are successfully replacing `/` with two backslashes, `\\`. Since a backslash must be encoded as `\\` in JSON output, a double backslash will end up represented as `\\\\`, so this:

```
"msg": "\\\\stuff\\\\foo\\\\thing"
```

Means you actually have the string:

```
\\stuff\\foo\\thing
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add an alternative solution:

If you're familiar with Python, you can just write a custom filter module and avoid multiple layers of escaping.  E.g., if you were to create `filter_plugins/reslash.py` with the following content:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python


def filter_reslash(val):
    return val.replace('/', '\\')


class FilterModule(object):
    filter_map = {
        'reslash': filter_reslash
    }

    def filters(self):
        return self.filter_map
```

You could then write your playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    - SecGroup: '/stuff/foo/thing'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ SecGroup | reslash }}"
```

That's arguably a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth, after countless struggles, this is what has worked for me without any workarounds:

#### Forward to Back Slash

```
ForwardtoBackSlash: "{{ 'c:/test' | regex_replace('\\\/', '\\\\') }}"
```

output:

```
c:\test
```

#### Single Slash to Double Slash

```
SingleSlashtoDoble: "{{ 'C:\test\logs\logfile.txt'| regex_replace('\\\\', '\\\\\\\\') }}"
```

Output:

```
C:\\test\\logs\\logfile.txt
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @larsks didn't entirely work for me as described. I needed to escape the backslash with double slashes `\` plus the guard character in order for it to work in the Ansible Playbook.

This works: `replace('/','\\;') | replace(';', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Another easy solution is to leave escaping backslash to ansible itself. This is how i would have done.

```
- set_fact:
    replacer: '\'

- name: With guard character
  debug:
    msg: '{{ SecGroup | replace("/",replacer)}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Same workaround if you want replace 1 backslash with double backslash on a windows path.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    - iis_manager_logdir: 'C:\inetpub\logs\manager-logs'
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        iis_mng_logs: "{{ iis_manager_logdir | regex_replace('\\\\', '\\\\;') | regex_replace(';', '\\\\') }}"
    - name: Original path
      debug:
        msg: "{{ iis_manager_logdir }}"
    - name: New path
      debug:
        msg: "{{ iis_mng_logs }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @larsks's answer i've managed to replace backslashes in ansible string variable value without intermediate replace. It's possible by supplying into `regex_replace` expression a regex quantifier `{1}` between last backslash and closing quote.

For example, expression like `{{ install_path | regex_replace('\\\\{1}', '/') }}` replaces all occurences of backslash `\` to forward slash `/`. It was used to replace Windows path delimiters with Unix-like ones:

```
- name: install libs
  win_shell: "pip install --no-index --find-links \"file://{{ install_path | regex_replace('\\\\{1}', '/') }}/libs\" attrs requests"
  become: true
```